# JP Morgan CreditMetrics

Tags: portfolio-management, risk, risk-management, credit-risk

I am trying to apply CreditMetrics on a 2 bond portfolio. As far as I know, this model returns the expected recovery rate and the volatility between those 2 bonds, so my question is how I calculate that portfolio credit VaR. Do I have to multipply the volatility by the exposure? And how this model works with 3 or more bonds/issuers?